# How can I build a table result with "eventReactive" in shiny

Tags: dataframe, matrix, shiny, rbind, cbind

How can I create a "table result" to each relationship I assumed in the selectInput "Col" and "Row"?  Dinamicaly, after each press 'ok' botom.

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
    h4("Give a valor between 0 to 5, to each col/row relationship"),
    uiOutput("colrow"),
    hr(),
    h5("Result:"),
    tableOutput("result")
))
shinyServer(
  function(input, output, session) {
    cols <<- c("Select"="", "col01" = "c01", "col02" = "c02")
    rows <<- c("Select"="", "row01" = "r01", "row02" = "r02")
    values <<- c("Select"="", 1:5)
    output$colrow <- renderUI({
      div(selectInput("ipt_col", label = "Col",
                  choices = c(cols),
                  selected = cols[1],
                  width = "50%"),
         selectInput("ipt_row", label = "Row",
                  choices = c(rows),
                  selected = rows[1],
                  width = "50%"),
         selectInput("ipt_vlr", label = "Value",
                  choices = c(values),
                  selected = ""),
         actionButton("bt_ok", "ok")
     )
})
colrow_vlr <- eventReactive(input$bt_ok, {      
  as.data.frame(matrix(input$ipt_vlr, 1,1, dimnames = list(input$ipt_row,input$ipt_col)))    
})
output$result <- renderTable({    
  colrow_vlr()    
})
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed your code a little bit and now it works. I added comments at where the changes were made.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  h4("Give a valor between 0 to 5, to each col/row relationship"),
  uiOutput("colrow"),
  hr(),
  h5("Result:"),
  # using DT which is recommended in shiny
  DT::dataTableOutput("result")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # no need to assign in the global env especially 'cols' is reserved
  cols <- c("Select"="", "col01" = "c01", "col02" = "c02")
  rows <- c("Select"="", "row01" = "r01", "row02" = "r02")
  values <- c("Select"="", 1:5)
  output$colrow <- renderUI({
    div(selectInput("ipt_col", label = "Col",
                    choices = cols, # no need to wrap with c()
                    selected = cols[1],
                    width = "50%"),
        selectInput("ipt_row", label = "Row",
                    choices = rows,
                    selected = rows[1],
                    width = "50%"),
        selectInput("ipt_vlr", label = "Value",
                    choices = values,
                    selected = ""),
        actionButton("bt_ok", "ok")
    )
  })
  colrow_vlr <- eventReactive(input$bt_ok, {      
    as.data.frame(matrix(input$ipt_vlr, 1,1, dimnames = list(input$ipt_row,input$ipt_col)))    
  })
  output$result <- DT::renderDataTable({    
    colrow_vlr()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thankyou very much, but it's the same result i did, instead by the DT::  

Let me try again:  

For each relation, col>row>value, I press botom 'ok', so I have one row on the table.  

If I do five relation, I got to have 5 rows on my table result.

I was clear ?
Thank you

Comment: @Fernando Can you explain what you are trying to do by modifying your question and be more specific?

Comment: ex:
I choose Col = "Col01" and Row="Row01" and Value="4" and finally, I click "OK" botom.

result, show me:
      c01
r01    4

**next**, I choose Col = "Col01" and Row="Row02" and Value="2" and "OK" botom.

result, should show me:
      c01
r01    4
r02    2

but on each OK botom click, it´s replace a data.frame content, and I can't to do code to add row.
How can I add new row at data.frame?

what about now ?
tks.